# GitHub Action: Setup common sets of ignored paths for both push and pull_request event

Tags: github, continuous-integration, yaml, continuous-deployment, github-actions

The way current [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpaths) describes that when setting up action we have to specify `paths-ignore` or `paths` for both `push` and `pull_request` event separately. Is there any way to specify a common sets of path that will be ignored by both events?